# Class to return a value when it is being referred

Tags: c#

I have a class with two strings in it.

I would like to return one string when ever the object is referred to.

Code snippet:

```
public class ABC
{
    public string A = "first";
    public string B = "second";
}

public class useABC
{
    ABC obj;

    if(obj == "first")
         Console.writeLine("True");
}
```

What should I do in my `ABC` class to print "True".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which object is refered to? `ABC`, `A`, `AB` or `useABC`? And by refer, you mean what?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the implicit or explicit operator. Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Note that too many implicit overloads can lead to a confusing or hard to use class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to override the equality operator (==).
Here's how to do it:  Remember you have to overload the operator in both orders.  Also, the compiler requires that you overload != at the same time.

```
public class ABS
{
    public string A;
    public string B;

    public static bool operator ==(ABS obj, string val){return obj.A == val;}
    public static bool operator !=(ABS obj, string val){return obj.A != val;}
    public static bool operator ==(string val, ABS obj){return obj.A == val;}
    public static bool operator !=(string val, ABS obj){return obj.A != val;}
}
```

The following code returns true for both expressions:

```
ABS abs = new ABS();
abs.A = "What?";

Assert.IsTrue(abs == "What?"); // true
Assert.IsTrue("What?" == abs); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing `IEquatable<string>` such that you can write `ABC.Equals("first")`.

```
public class ABS : IEquatable<string>
{
    string A, B;
    public bool Equals(string other)
    {
        return A.Equals(other) || B.Equals(other);
    }
}
```

and later

```
if( ABC.Equals("first") ) { Console.WriteLine("true"); }
```

Then you can also override the `==` operator, but it is not recommended for class types. Like with `string` it is recommended to use the `.Equals()` method to check for equality. Alternatively, you can just add a method `bool Contains(string other)` to check if string is in `A` or `B`.